# sl(2)-reps categorifying q-binomials

Tags: rt.representation-theory, characters

Recall that the [$q$-binomial coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_binomial_coefficient) $\big[\begin{smallmatrix}a\\b\end{smallmatrix}\big]$ is the Laurent polynomial in $q$ given by
$$
\big[\begin{smallmatrix}a\\b\end{smallmatrix}\big]=\frac{[a]!}{[b]![a-b]!}
$$
where $[n]!=[1][2][3]...[n]$, and $[i]=\tfrac{q^i-q^{-i}}{q-q^{-1}}=q^{i-1}+q^{i-3}+q^{i-5}+...+q^{-(i-1)}$.

Let $V_n$ be the $n$-dimensional irrep of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$.

> It is easy to check that there exists an isomorphism of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$-representations
> $$
> S^k V_{n+1} \cong \textstyle \bigwedge^k V_{n+k}
> $$
> between the $k$-th symmetric power of $V_{n+1}$ and the $k$-th exterior power of $V_{n+k}$, as both have $\big[\begin{smallmatrix}n+k\\k\end{smallmatrix}\big]$ as their character

**Proof:** We exhibit a basis of weight vectors of $S^k V_{n+1}$, a basis of weight vectors of $\bigwedge^k V_{n+k}$, and a bijection between these bases which respects the weights.
Let $x_0,\ldots, x_n$ be the standard basis of $V_{n+1}$, and let
$y_1,\ldots y_{n+k}$ be the standard basis of $V_{n+k}$.
Then $x_{i_1}{\cdot}\, x_{i_2} \cdot... \cdot x_{i_k}\mapsto y_{i_1+1}\wedge y_{i_2+2}\wedge...\wedge y_{i_k+k}$ is the desired bijection. $\square$

The problem with the above proof is that it only proves the existence of an isomorphism, without actually constructing one.

> **Question:** It there a **natural** isomorphism of $\mathfrak{sl}(2)$-representations $S^k V_{n+1} \cong \textstyle \bigwedge^k V_{n+k}$ that one can write?

Comment: Several related questions/answers, with references: https://mathoverflow.net/a/42859/41291 https://mathoverflow.net/q/268998/41291 https://mathoverflow.net/a/269056/41291 https://mathoverflow.net/a/320927/41291

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes there is. In my article with Chipalkatti ["On the Wronskian combinants of binary forms"](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0022404906001812) in J. Pure Appl. Algebra, we gave an explicit construction in Section 2.5. We called it the Wronskian isomorphism because when followed (on the sym-sym side) by complete symetrization, we get the usual Wronskian (in homogenized form). Now, I'm sure the map was known a long time before. The earliest reference I found is the [Thesis](https://books.google.com/books?id=vXpAsTWGZTQC&printsec=frontcover#v=onepage&q&f=false) by  Cyparissos Stephanos from 1884.
Essentially, the map is nothing more than dividing by the Vandermonde in order to turn antisymmetric functions into symmetric ones, a kind of Boson-Fermion correspondence.

You might be interested in a new development about this map regarding characteristic $p$. See the article ["Koszul modules and Green’s conjecture"](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00222-019-00894-1) by Aprodu et al., Sec 3.4.